# How to include the private key in paramiko after fetching from string?

Tags: python, django, ssh, paramiko, ssh-keys

I am working with paramiko, I have generated my private key and tried it which was fine. Now I am working with Django based application where I have already copied the private key in database.

I saved my private key in `charField` in Django model. I am facing a problem in the following code:

```
host = "192.154.34.54"
username = "lovestone"
port = 25
pkey = "------" # I saved my key in this string
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(server, username=username, port=port, pkey=?)
```

What should I do in this case? How should I pass the private key in `SSH.connect` while I stored it in `string` in database?

### Updated

Even i can't use the IO i.e. fetch the key from database and write it to a file and then use the saved file object and pass into `from_private_key(cls, file_obj, password=None)` `enter code here`because this is web based application and it is not a generic key. Every user have it's own private key.

Comment: @Amit Got a solution for this?

Answer (score 14):

if you cannot save the private keys to files, that would be the the main reason to use [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html): StringIO takes a string and turns it into a file-like object, but nothing is written to the file system. It allows you to pass in file-like objects when all you have is a string: i.e. exactly cases like this.

```
import paramiko, StringIO

key_string = "------" # I saved my key in this string
not_really_a_file = StringIO.StringIO(key_string)
private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(not_really_a_file)

not_really_a_file.close()
```

That works for me, and you should be able to connect with that object:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host="example.com", username="root", pkey=private_key)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) for creating file-like object with your stored private key and [PKey](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.PKey-class.html)'s class method [from_private_key](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.PKey-class.html#from_private_key), so you will create [PKey](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.PKey-class.html) instance and you can pass it to [connect](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SSHClient-class.html#connect) method.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I got your solution but it will not work for me :P
Would you please see the updated section of question.