# Can I use ssh/scp with a private key stored in a DB?

Tags: python, database, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm developing a python/django application that, among other things, needs to push a file over ssh/scp to another host. For security, I want to use key-based auth, but I want to store the private key in the django database, rather than on the filesystem. Is there any way to do this, short of retrieving the key from the DB, writing to a temporary file, then specifying that file?

Answer (score 0):

Using paramiko you can do some tricks to avoid having to write the key to the filesystem.
using [paramiko connect](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SSHClient-class.html#connect) you can specify a pkey as an argument.

`PKey` object has a [`from_private_key`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.PKey-class.html#from_private_key) method that takes a file object (`StringIO` with your key that you pull from your db) something like:

```
f = StringIO.StringIO()
# retreive your key from db
f.write(your_key)
private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(f)
ssh.connect(server, username=username,pkey=private_key)
```

[How to include the private key in paramiko after fetching from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994139/how-to-include-the-private-key-in-paramiko-after-fetching-from-string)